# cannot boot to Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu on another internal disk

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, bootloader, boot-repair

I have a Windows 7 64bit desktop (sda). I've been getting into linux after experimenting with raspbian/raspberry pi 2. decided to install Ubuntu (sdc) on a spare internal drive separate from the Windows disk.

Ubuntu is working great but the problem is I can no longer boot into Windows.
I'm guessing the Ubuntu install may have altered the way my Windows disk boots.

I have run boot-repair via Ubuntu with the log here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10989305/

When I run the actual automatic repair it gives an error stating GPT found and to create a partition for the grub_bios, which I have done but still no luck.

I should get my windows disk/usb back off a friend soon to help repair windows boot. In the meantime I thought maybe someone here could help shed some light on my situation, maybe I would learn from this.

Comment: Try running `sudo update-grub` in a terminal before rebooting, to see if Windows appears in GRUB.